# How to make Relay and React Routing work properly?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, relayjs, react-router-relay

I am starting out with Relay and trying to make my routing work properly.
Unfortunately, I am not having much of luck.

Here is the error I am getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Component.getFragment is not a function

Here is the code I have for your reference:

**index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Relay from 'react-relay';
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import {RelayRouter} from 'react-router-relay';

import App from './modules/app';
import Home from './modules/home';

const AppQueries = {
  store: (Component) => Relay.QL `query {
    store {
      ${Component.getFragment('store')}
    }
  }`
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <RelayRouter history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={App} queries={AppQueries}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
    </Route>
  </RelayRouter>, 
document.getElementById('ch-root'));
```

**app.jsx**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Relay from 'react-relay';
import Header from './ui/header';
import Footer from './ui/footer';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="ch-container">
        <Header/>
        <section id="ch-body">
          {this.props.children}
        </section>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

App = Relay.createContainer(App, {
  fragments: {
    store: (Component) => Relay.QL `
      fragment on Store {
        ${Component.getFragment('store')}
      }
     `
  }
});

export default App;
```

**home.jsx**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Relay from 'react-relay';
import Loader from './ui/loader';
import AccountSelector from './account/account-selector';

const APP_HOST = window.CH_APP_HOST;
const CURR_HOST = `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.host}`;

class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    activeAccount: null,
    loading: true
  }

  render() {
    const {activeAccount, loading} = this.state;

    if (loading) {
      return <Loader/>;
    }

    if (!activeAccount && !loading) {
      return <AccountSelector/>;
    }

    return (
      <h1>Hello!</h1>
    );
  }
}

Home = Relay.createContainer(Home, {
  fragments: {
    store: () => Relay.QL `
      fragment on Store {
        accounts {
          unique_id,
          subdomain
        }
      }
     `
  }
});

export default Home;
```

**UPDATE**

I made few changes suggested by `freiksenet` as below. But that raises the following two issues:

1. What would happen when I change the route and a component other than `Home` gets rendered by the `App` component?
2. I now get this error:

> Warning: RelayContainer: Expected prop `store` to be supplied to
>   `Home`, but got `undefined`. Pass an explicit `null` if this is
>   intentional.

Here are the changes:

*index.jsx*

```
const AppQueries = {
  store: () => Relay.QL `query {
    store 
  }`
};
```

*app.jsx*

```
import Home from "./home";

...

App = Relay.createContainer(App, {
  fragments: {
    store: () => Relay.QL `
      fragment on Store {
        ${Home.getFragment('store')}
      }
     `
  }
});
```

Comment: The error means that it doesn't know what `Component` is. You'll have to import it in a similar fashion to how you imported `App` and `Home`. I'm assuming the error is generated on the `index` file?

Comment: @Moon Response to your UPDATE 1:  
Question 2: You didn't pass any query for `Home` component. In index.jsx file, Change `<IndexRoute component={Home}/>` to `<IndexRoute component={Home}/> queries={AppQueries}`.  
Question 1: As @freiksenet has already mentioned, `App` doesn't have to be container. The other component(s) rendered by `App` just needs to have necessary fragments defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fragment definitions don't actually get Components as arguments, but a map of variables of the container, you only need to use them to have conditional fragments based on variable values.

Relay Route queries don't accept any arguments.

Here are the changes you need to make.

Route queries in Relay just need to specify the root query you are going to retrieve in this route, without the fragment.

*index.jsx*

```
const AppQueries = {
  store: () => Relay.QL `query {
    store 
  }`
};
```

Your App component actually doesn't use any relay data, so you can just export normal component instead of container.

```
export default class App extends Component {
```

If you'd need to pass some Relay data to it, you don't need to include child fragments, because fragments inclusion is only needed when you directly render other containers as direct children (not as this.props.children).

Then in Router you need to move the queries to Home.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <RelayRouter history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} queries={AppQueries} />
    </Route>
  </RelayRouter>, 
document.getElementById('ch-root'));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I updated my code as suggested and then updated my question with new observations.

Comment: @Moon Aha. It seems I misunderstood what you are trying to do a bit. Corrected now.